# Duplicate library linking with Stack and Nix

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

I'm using `stack`'s support for `nix` to build a library that depends on `gfortran`. Everything builds normally, but when running I get the error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But when I run `ldd` on the binary I get two entries for `libgfortran`:

```
libgfortran.so.3 => not found
libgfortran.so.3 => /nix/store/aw2rsa61iq2xwh99khgfnhmz6amzqr7v-gfortran-4.9.3/lib
                    /libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f32dc3e0000)
```

That is, it links correctly but only for one of the two entries. Is there a solution for that? What could be the source of the problem?

For information, the project depends on `openblas` and `arpack` and I'm using `nix` in Arch Linux.

Comment: did you find a solution on reddit?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen not yet, I've tried multiple approaches but nothing is really working. I didn't have time to decompose the problem yet and find the source, but I feel it's connected to arpack.

Comment: It would be great if you could share details on how to reproduce this problem, i.e. which package are you building exactly and what command line are you using to build it?

Comment: @guaraqe If you still want an answer to this question, you should really try to add more details. Currently it's glossing over much important information, making it hard or even impossible to analyze the underlying problem.